# Issue with the yaml file for presenting Notebook from a Jupyterlite expressed from a Gitlab Repository (Gitlab Pages)

Tags: jupyter-notebook, path, gitlab, gitlab-ci.yml, jupyterlite

I'm trying to configure a Gitlab Page which opens a jupyterlite which then offers the Notebooks that we have placed in a folder.
It is in the .gitlab-ci.yml file that we must make a clarification to specify how jupyterlite finds the notebooks to present…
Apparently, that's where it gets stuck: I have my Gitlab page which opens on a jupyterlite... but I don't have any Notebook presented in the tree...
I sent You my code of the yml file
#################

###############
Here is my URL…
https://gitlab.com/fialaire_david/jupyterlite14
If anyone has an idea...I'm all ears. THANKS !
David

I tried this yml file :

```
image: python
pages:
stage: deploy
before_script:
- python -m pip install jupyterlite
script:
- jupyter lite build --contents content --output-dir public

artifacts:
paths:
- public
only:
- main
```

But no notebooks appeared in the tree